# "list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType" Error

Tags: python

I get an error when the board is filled and all spaces have been occupied and I don't know why?

Here's my code for where the error is:

```
def insertLetter(letter, pos):
    board[pos] = letter
```

Comment: you're only initing `edgesOpen` if 5 is in `possibleMoves` but you are using it outside of that if

Answer (score 0):

The line `edgesOpen = []` is indented too much, putting it inside the `if 5 in possibleMoves:` block (and after the return statement, making it dead code). Therefore `edgesOpen` is not defined. You need to remove one level of indentation from that line to fix the error.